# joomla link on custom module?

Tags: hyperlink, joomla

Hi I am new in joomla and have a question about href tag on custom module.

```
<a href="#">record1</a>
```

I have this on my view file and how can i give a link on this href?
the link must be support while i change the url type suppose seo friendly urls by global configuration. I have no idea about it. is link from database or statically? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/JRoute), simple way to write Joomla URLs. Your urls will be rewritten automatically if you use Joomla SEF urls or 3rd party SEF components like sh404SEF.